# Eliminating dates by characteristics in time series

Tags: r, time, time-series

I´m analyzing absenteeism data for schools and am seeking a bit of help.  For every day, I have 360 rows (classrooms) containing that day´s (column 1) number of absent (column 2) and non-absent students (column 3).

Some days (holidays) only have, say, 20 classes reporting, because the other 340 classes did not have class.  I want to ELIMINATE those rows from my dataset.  In other words, I want to eliminate

classes and want to eliminate from my dataset all entries in which the total number of entries for the date are less than a certain number.  In other words, I want to eliminate all rows with date x if the total number of rows containg date x are less than 200.

Here´s what I´ve got so far:

```
for (i in c(min(df$date):max(df$date))){
  b <- df[df$date == i,]
  z <- as.vector(ifelse(nrow(b[which(b$date==i),]) <200, "FALSE", "TRUE"))
  print(z)
  df$newcolumn <- z
}
```

This prints z, which goes day-by-day telling me if that day meets my conditions, but I cannot figure out a way to incorporate z back into the dataframe´s 10000s of rows.  Instead, my df$newcolumn is simply populated by all TRUEs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to do for real without a reproducible example, but doesn't something like `df[ ! df$date %in% z, ]` work?

`%in%` will return a logical vector of whether each element exists in the other vector, `!` negates so it returns TRUE if it's >200, and the `[ rowselector,]` selects rows from the data.frame.